# 401 Error on maps.googleapis.com call

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I am getting a 401 error on a call to maps.googleapis.com but I'm puzzled as to why. I'm hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

On the server, I have a function that includes this code:

```
private string DoGoogleWork(string address) {
    string GoogleServerAPIKey = "My Server API key";
    string strXML = string.Empty;
    using(WebClient c = new WebClient()){
         var geoCodeUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + addr.Replace(' ', '+') + "&key=" + GoogleServerAPI;
         try
         {
             strXML = c.DownloadString(geoCodeUrl); // raises a 401 exception
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             ErrorLogger(ex.Message);
         }
    }

    //
    // Parse the XML and do some work with the results
    //
}
```

There are no IP restrictions on my server API  key, so I'm not sure why I'm getting a 401 error. I'm hoping someone can see something I'm missing.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means [Invalid authorization header](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials). The access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Refresh your access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct the user through the [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and you need to get a new auth token.

Check this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502063/google-maps-tracks-api-401-invalid-credentials).

Comment: We are not using OAuth for this. This is a server-to-server call.

Comment: (more info).  This code is identical to code that is in use on other servers. So i'm not sure why it's failing in this case. Puzzling.